# How to turn off alert sounds/sound effects on Gnome from terminal?

Tags: gnome, audio, configuration

I usually turn the alert sound (by default a water drop sound) off by going to control-center→Sound→Sound Effects and muting the Alert volume. This is in Gnome.

I wanted to turn it off in a custom live build of Debian by default, but I can't figure where this setting is stored. I tried dconf and looked around config directories extensively without success. I tried `find ~ -mmin -1` also `gio monitor` and `inotifywatch` without success. The only output by `find ~ -mmin -1` was `.config/dconf/` and `.config/dconf/user` which get edited all the time the control center is opened anyway. I replaced this user file in a vm to test and all dconf settings were updated except the one I need (the alert sound). I also tried `dconf watch /` which gave no output when I tried editing the alert sound setting

I'd like someone to tell me how to mute this setting from command line and possibly tell me where it is stored.

Comment: That's extremely close, I can't really edit the preferences of the alert sounds from this dconf key but I can completely disable them, which is enough for me. I don't know if the question should be removed as a duplicate though.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This can be achieved by this command

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/sound/event-sounds "false"
```

However, this doesn't turn off the sound volume slider effect.

To completely turn off the sound effects the closest way I've found was to live boot into a clean iso of the distro and open the System settings > Sound > Sound effects and turn these sounds off as preferred, then copy the file ~/.config/pulse/*-stream-volumes.tdb and save it. Then, to turn off the "sound effects" on an installed environment or while building a custom version of the distro do

```
cp saved-pulse-volumes.tdb ~/.config/pulse/*-stream-volumes.tdb
```

Comment: thanks! to completely turn off i have find all settings by keyword `bell`.

Comment: @cablewelo2ma or `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.sound event-sounds false`.

Comment: This still works on 22.04 Ubuntu LTS. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is another key you can set with dconf:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/sound/input-feedback-sound "false"
```

which should disable to play sounds on input events.

Comment: This key doesn't exist in my distro, are you sure this is debian?