# How to COMPLETELY turn off system beep sounds forever for good for real

Tags: debian, audio, kde, nautilus

I use Nautilus to explore my files. I use a Debian-based OS with KDE Plasma 5.

I use the keyboard a lot. When I press the key up when navigating files, if I'm already at the extremity of the list of files, Nautilus sends a big system beep which I will hear at 100% volume through my headphones. My reaction is comparable to getting electrified.

I have placed the following lines in `~/.bashrc` for the sudo (root) user and for my regular desktop user:

```
# Turn off system beep in console:
xset b off
xset b 0 0 0
```

However, despite the beep going away from some places in the OS (such as erasing an empty line in the gnome-terminal), it's still in Nautilus. I believe it's because Nautilus doesn't source any of the `.bashrc` or because it ignores the `xset` commands.

How do I fix this?

What I need might be at a deeper level than the `.bashrc`, some file that is executed by everything, but which can still control the sound. Otherwise, disabling the sound another way or replacing it could be interesting.

Comment: Is it a system beep (so loud tone), or sound (bark/drip/dong etc for gnome)? If its the former its probably system level (in which case, try disabling the `pcspkr` module, or using a different sound card - if its the latter you will have to turn off the sound in system settings (including Gnome's as in Stephen's answer)

Comment: Just to make it explicit for those who didn't realize it: `~/.bashrc` is the user configuration file of the `bash` shell, the default Debian terminal shell. If you realize that, it's pretty obvious why bash settings do not affect other applications like Nautilus.

Comment: `alsamixer` may be usable for adjusting some volume's as well. The bashrc could work in some scenarios, but for root it will only run when root logs in, and nautilus will get likely get most settings from elsewhere!

Comment: Some sound cards have the system beep as a separate channel which can be muted.

Comment: Try using `~/.profile` instead of `~/.bashrc`. As noted by @MSalters, `~/.bashrc` is run when you open a new terminal, and not when you log in. `~/.profile` is run when you log in. (Laughed good on your reaction, I've experienced it myself!)

Comment: See also [Why Ctrl+G doesn't produce a beep?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/401168) which gives you a list of things to look at.

Comment: Wire cutters; just cut it out ^^

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: bash beeps if you try to tab-complete something that can't be tab-completed. So I'm not sure how that's an argument.

Comment: @esoterik: Ah. The Alexandrian solution to this ^G-ordian knot of a question. :-)

Comment: @Wilf, "Is it a system beep (so loud tone), or sound (bark/drip/dong etc for gnome)?": To be clear, I believe that's a system beep at a somehow lower level than a "sound". It sounds like a perfect 1-tone wave (that might be a square or triangle or saw audio waveform, but not a sine wave). It has a fixed duration, and holding the key down will stack-repeat the sound.

Answer (score 67):

I do not know what sound KDE does, but if you mean system beep, just disable loading of the `pcspkr` module. As root do:

`rmmod pcspkr ; echo "blacklist pcspkr" >>/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

Comment: This only disables the PC speaker, which Nautilus doesn't use. You're solving the wrong problem.

Comment: I was amused yet annoyed to learn my new Lenovo laptop has a speaker. Every time I hit backspace one too many times, have a failed Ctrl+F search in Firefox, have a failed tab completion... always this loud, obnoxious beep. Instead of configuring each piece of software, removing the pcspkr mod worked! (I needed to use `/sbin/rmmod` by the way, PATH was not set correctly for root.)

Comment: I have  a Lenovo Y700 and I also was surprise that it has the old and good PC Speaker inside. So this solution worked to me! Thank you. No more annoying bells and beeps.

Comment: After an Debian upgrade from Bullseye to Woodworm(currently "testing"), obnoxious popping sounds started aggravating me on keystrokes like @Luc reports. I had previously disabled all sound effects I could. Indeed disabling this damn module worked. What a waste of time to have to deal with this. This answer may or may not have been suited for the original question, but likely to be spot on for future readers. Thank you Edheldil

Answer (score 45):

Short of muting the sound entirely or disconnecting your headphones, there is no system-wide setting for events which will be followed by *all* applications. In your case especially, since you’re using Nautilus on a KDE system, you’ll run into issues since Nautilus won’t follow your desktop’s configured behaviour.

Nautilus uses GNOME’s settings. If you have the GNOME control centre, you can disable sound effects there — go to the sound settings, and disable sound effects. Alternatively, run `dconf-editor`, go to “org/gnome/desktop/sound”, and disable “event-sounds” and “input-feedback-sounds”. You can do this from the command line too, see [How to turn off alert sounds/sound effects on Gnome from terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444681/86440) for details.

Comment: I don't think this is true. If it is using the PC speaker, you can disable that globally.

Comment: @forest the question states “Nautilus will send a big system beep which I will hear at 100% volume through my headphones”. That can’t be disabled by disabling the PC speaker.

Comment: Nitpicking, but there is a kernel configuration setting that sends requests to trigger the PC speaker through the ALSA driver instead, but I don't know if any distros actually do that by default. But that's probably not the case, so good point.

Comment: @forest there’s really a terminology issue in the question — Nautilus doesn’t use the system beep.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. dconf-editor path “org/gnome/desktop/sound” had beep sound(event sounds) on. I turned it off.

Answer (score 19):

[To mute Gnome alerts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444869/60622):

```
$ dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/sound/event-sounds "false"
```

[Equivalently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/309228/60622):

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.sound event-sounds false
```

Comment: Oops, this duplicates Stephen Kitt's answer.  Consider this the tl;dr version.

Comment: I think this is more direct to the solution. But both are great answers!

Comment: Thank you so much, I was losing my mind

Answer (score 1):

The `xset` command you're using operates on the X server/X session, not the terminal, so `.bashrc` or similar is not the right place to put it. If Nautilus is really beeping via the X server's bell function, I would expect the `xset` to stop it, if you've already opened a terminal (and thereby run the command) beforehand.

If that works, what you need to do is get the command run as part of starting/logging in under X. The traditional way to do this is via a `.xsession` or `.xinitrc` file; however, these files (scripts) were traditionally expected to run your window manager/desktop environment session program, as the final line via `exec`, and if you just go dropping in a script containing nothing but `xset`, you might find yourself unable to login under X (rather, immediately getting logged out when you do). Figuring out the right thing to do here is going to be somewhat specific to the OS/distro's X and desktop environment setup, so I feel like I'm leaving this answer somewhat incomplete, but as a source of direction for where to look.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried every single thing in this article, and more, and none of them worked. Sure some disabled the system beep for the terminal application, but all of the OS-related beeps were still on. What finally worked? Finding and renaming the dang sound file (and logging out and back in to my X session). `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/bell.ogg` I renamed the above to `bell2.ogg`.

`sudo mv /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/bell.ogg /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/bell2.ogg`

Now I can use my computer without wanting to flip my desk over.

Who the hell thought a super loud beep every time you pressed a key was a good idea? It's like some sort of weird psychological experiment.

Note, this will probably revert itself if the `ubuntu-sounds` package requires an upgrade, and you'll need to re-move the file off.

Comment: We need to know who made this bell noise a thing.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue on Zorin 16 (Zorin 16, GNOME Shell 3.38.4).

In the settings dialog you can set the Alert sound to a few builtin options Default, Bark, Glass... However there is no option to disable it.
I chose to hide the glass.ogg sound file.  Glass being transparent, I found it the most obvious association with no sound among the builtin options.

```
sudo mv /usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/glass.ogg /usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/hide_glass.ogg
```

As a result, picking the "Glass" sound will effectively mute the alert sound, while keeping the option to re-enable the alert sound if/when desired.

I also disabled the Terminal bell in the Terminal preferences.
Those two measures seem to cover it for me.